# How to create a table in firebase? (Previous title: How to create a database in firebase?)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to test working with `Firebase`.
I want to use 'Firebase` in the application.
I created a project.
How to create a table in firebase??

[image]

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#create_a_database

Comment: @Renaud Tarnec I don't understand...
I get to the page that is shown in my picture....
I don't understand what to do next?

Comment: Firebase has a [detailed video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP7quzFmWBY) explaining all basic of realtime database that might help you understand how to use it based on your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our comments below your question:

If you have followed what is explained in the Firebase [documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start#create_a_database) I referred to in my comment and you get to the page shown in the screenshot in your question, then the next steps are the following:

1. Learn how to [structure data for Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data).
2. Start [creating some data in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#write_data)
3. Learn how to [secure your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)
4. [Read the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data) that is in your database
5. Read all the doc to understand all the possibilities offered by the Realtime Database service

---

**Note #1:** When coming from the SQL world, it is quite common to ask "How to create a table?".

There is actually no concept of table in the Realtime Database. If you read the doc about [how to structure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) you'll find the following remark:

> All Firebase Realtime Database data is stored as JSON objects. You can
> think of the database as a cloud-hosted JSON tree. Unlike a SQL
> database, there are no tables or records. When you add data to the
> JSON tree, it becomes a node in the existing JSON structure with an
> associated key.

---

**Note #2:** The links in points 2 and 4 above are about the JS SDK but you'll find in the documentation menu the corresponding documentation for other languages/SDKs (Android, iOS, etc...)

---

**Note #3:** The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database#implementation_path) lists a similar list of next steps.

Comment: I'm still studying your links, but I'll write my thoughts..
I'm confused... I have created a database.. If I understood correctly... I need to create a table. Or do I understand something wrong?
-------
I want to use firebase in Xamarin (C#)... I've been reading blogs. I tested the app... I am creating a client to work with the database.... But I don't understand how to create a table... Resume: how to create a table?

Comment: https://medium.com/@jonwoods590/firebase-realtime-database-with-a-xamarin-forms-mobile-app-56c85be422de

https://parallelcodes.com/xamarin-forms-integrating-firebase-database-tutorial/

Comment: "Resume: how to create a table?" => There is no concept of table in the Realtime Database. If you read the doc about [how to structure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) you'll find the following: "All Firebase Realtime Database data is stored as JSON objects. You can think of the database as a cloud-hosted JSON tree. **Unlike a SQL database, there are no tables or records**. When you add data to the JSON tree, it becomes a node in the existing JSON structure with an associated key."

Comment: The links you share seem to be correct. Just start writing data as shown in these tutorials and "voilà" your data is saved to the database. For more complex data model, the best is to take the time to read the Firebase documentation which is very good.

Comment: Tarmec Your previous comment is what I wanted to hear.
I think you should add it to your answer.